# How to add extension to unknown extension file

Tags: powershell

I've learned how to change multiple file extension into new extension through powershell like all of .png to .jpg
But what if my original files are unknown extension, just "file" type
I've tried `"*."` instead of `"*.jpg"` but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question lacks details. How are you trying to change file extensions? What doesn't work and how? (Remember: Nobody can see your screen.)

Comment: Have you done a search for this? [How can I determine file type without an extension on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/how-can-i-determine-file-type-without-an-extension-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.` means "anything, and then 1 dot" - but your extension-less files will not have a dot, which is why it fails.

Inspect the `Extension` property of the files instead:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ''}
```